# Why must a static constructor be parameterless?

Tags: c#

I'm encountering this error:

> 'LnkScript.LnkScript.KillstreakHud.KillstreakHud(InfinityScript.Entity)': a static constructor must be parameterless   C:\Users\home\Desktop\LnkScripts.cs 61  20  LnkScript

My source code:

```
public class KillstreakHud : BaseScript
{
   static KillstreakHud(Entity player)
   {
      string killstreak = "^3Killstreak:^3" + player.GetField<int>("killstreak").ToString();
      HudElem hudelem = HudElem.CreateFontString(player, "hudsmall", 1f);
      HudElem.SetPoint("TOPCENTER", "TOPCENTER");
      HudElem.SetText(killstreak);
      base.OnInterval(300, delegate
      {
         killstreak = "^3Killstreak:^3" + player.GetField<int>("killstreak").ToString();
         hudelem.SetText(Killstreak);
         return true;
      });
   }
}
```

Clearly, my static constructor is not parameterless, and the compiler takes umbrage at this fact. But why?

Comment: either remove the parameter or the static

Comment: The error message is quite clear. You don't instantiate a static class, so how can it have a parameter? You won't be able to supply it.

Comment: ":) XD" You seem unusually pleased that you've run into an error.

Comment: Did you even read the error message?

Answer (score 9):

A static constructor must be parameterless because nothing ever calls it, it is invoked when you access a static member or create an instance of the class, but not directly (it is called by the runtime).

The solution: **Remove your parameters, or make it non-static**

Reference for static constructors: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx

To make it non-static (note that it will need to be invoked directly with the `new` keyword now):

```
public KillstreakHud(Entity player)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: They're not called at program startup...they're called at some indeterminate point before their type is used, if their type is used..

Comment: Static constructors are not called on startup, they are called before an instance is created or some static member is referenced.

Comment: @Servy, you are absolutley right. I apologize for my mistake. Updated to match reality :)

Comment: How To make it non static

Comment: @user3688690, just remove the static :) updated my answer to include this info.

Comment: @user3688690, well work through them! Not to sound too harsh, but the errors should give you quite a big hint as to how to fix them. For starters, your delegate syntax looks really weird, that probably has  a few errors. Try a standard lambda expression instead.

Comment: when i remove it i get more errors when i try build solution it does not build into .dll

Comment: @user3688690 Thats not how this works. If you have a separate question, just ask a new one. That being said, SO is not intended to be a compilation-fix service (though some good questions come out of it). For each error: (1) Read the error, what does it imply is wrong? Is there an obvious way to fix that? (2) Google the error, see what existing explanations/fix steps are out there. (3) If it is really weird, and you don't understand why its broken, ask a new SO question. If you had enough rep to chat, I would consider using that, but you haven't really shown enough effort even for that.

Comment: @user3688690 And for the love of god, if you're going to ask about an error you're getting, include the actual error!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this is a limitation of the language. Static is something that is called once and does not change. There is no reason (apart from not implemented) why it cannot accept a parameter with the understanding that it will only ever use the parameter value once.
This limitation of the language is what has made such a mess in "public static class ConfigurationManager"
There are lost of people asking can I use a different config file?
If the constructor could accept a parameter then this would be easy
(but it can't so you have to make your own config)

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose of declaring a data member static is that it should be available in all instances of the class. When a data member is shared among different instances it is imperative that data should be consistent among all the instances of the class.

**And also there is no way to call static constructor explicitly.
Therefore the purpose of having a parameterized static constructor is useless.**

a static constructor is implicitly called when:-
1. static data member is referenced.
or
2.object of the class containing static constructor is created.

visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors